# What does it mean to 'Link Binary with Library?'

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm having difficulty understanding what exactly happens when you tell your project to link a binary with library. I understand that it is required to include a framework in your project, but can anyone shed some light on what is going on behind the scenes? All I really get from it is that the project now has access to the header files of the framework.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_(computing)) is your friend.

Comment: and so is stack overflow! thanks a lot! also found this http://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/cse378/97au/help/compilation.html